# add Insert Shortcode Option in Wordpress Wysiwyg

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, shortcode

I've been creating my own shortcodes for some time now, which have been really helpful. I was wondering if there is a way to add a button, just above the default Wordpress editor similar to the "Add Media" button that would be "Add Shortcode", when clicking on it - there's a list of available shortcodes that would automatically insert into the text editor field and then or course any details within the shortcode could manually be changed. Just thought this might be easier than keeping a text document with shortcodes in it to copy and paste.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution.

// Php - add into the function.php

```
function rawebdev_shordcode_dialog_template() {
  // template for the dialog
  $dialog = '<div id="custom-shortcode-url" class="hidden" >';
  $dialog .= '<input type="text" 
               placeholder="[myshortcode]"
               name="custom-shortcode-url-input" 
               id="custom-shortcode-url-input" />';
 $dialog .= '</div>';
 echo $dialog;
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'rawebdev_shordcode_dialog_template');

function rawebdev_custom_button_after_addmedia() {
  echo '<a href="#" id="rawebde-shortcode-btn" class="button">Add Shortcode</a>';
}
add_action('media_buttons', 'rawebdev_custom_button_after_addmedia', 25);


function rawebdev_shortcode_button_js_file() {
  // include file only in admin area
  if( is_admin() ){
    // JS
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'rawebdev_shortcode_button_js', // handle
        get_template_directory_uri(). 'js/shortcode-button.js',// source
        array('jquery-ui-dialog' ),   // dependencies
        fileatime( get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/shortcode-button.js'  ) // version
    );
    wp_enqueue_style (  'wp-jquery-ui-dialog');

  }

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_media', 'rawebdev_shortcode_button_js_file');
```

create a file- shortcode-button.js and add a snippet

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // creation of the dialog
        $('#custom-shortcode-url').dialog({
            title: 'Insert Shortcode',
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons: {
                "Insert Shortcode": function () {
                    let str = $('#custom-shortcode-url-input').val();
                    // insert text in editor
                    wp.media.editor.insert(str);
                    // close dialogue
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('#rawebde-shortcode-btn').click(function () {
            $('#custom-shortcode-url-input').val('[mycustomshortcode]');
            $('#custom-shortcode-url').dialog('open');
        });

    });

});
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn’t answer any question - it’s a giant block of code. Stack Overflow is not for posting requirements and having orhers post solutions .